# Strange null returned form async function

Tags: flutter, url, google-cloud-firestore, storage

I'm trying to get the URL of an uploaded image file on firebase storage, but I'm facing a very strange behavior.

Please take a look at the code below, problem is explained in the comented lines:

```
Future<String?> _uploadImage(String fileName, File imageFile) async {
    try {
      // Uploading the selected image with some custom meta data
      await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref(fileName)
          .putFile(
              imageFile,
              SettableMetadata(customMetadata: {
                'uploaded_by': 'Some guy',
                'description': 'Some description...'
              }))
          .then((imgUploadTaskSnapshot) async {
        switch (imgUploadTaskSnapshot.state) {
              case TaskState.paused:
                break;
              case TaskState.running:
                break;
              case TaskState.success:
                return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(fileName).getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
                  print('url : $fileURL'); // here i get a value -> url : https://firebasest.....
                  return fileURL; // but here null is returned
                });
                break;
              case TaskState.canceled:
                break;
              case TaskState.error:
                break;
            }
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      //Todo: handle errors
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
}

Future<List<String>?> uploadImages(List<Map<String, dynamic>> images) async {
    try {
      List<String> imgsURLs = <String>[];
      for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        await _uploadImage(images[i]['filename'], images[i]['imagefile'])
            .then((imgURL) {
          print('imgURL: $imgURL'); // cause here i get -> imgURL: null
          if (imgURL != null) {
            imgsURLs.add(imgURL);
          }
        });
      }
      print('imgsURLs: $imgsURLs');
      return imgsURLs;
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      //Todo: hadle errors
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the body in the `then` callback is another function. So calling `return` inside it will return the value, but not for `_uploadImage` but for the anonymous callback.

The returned value will actually apprear as the result of awaiting on the callback. You can add the return to further return it as the result of `_uploadImage`

```dart
return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(fileName).getDownloadURL().then(...
```

What is also worth noting is that you don't have to use `then` when you are in the async function. This is the main benefit of having those - you don't need to deal with callbacks.

```dart
Future<String?> _uploadImage(String fileName, File imageFile) async {
  try {
    // Uploading the selected image with some custom meta data
    final imgUploadTaskSnapshot = await FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref(fileName)
        .putFile(
            imageFile,
            SettableMetadata(customMetadata: {
              'uploaded_by': 'Some guy',
              'description': 'Some description...'
            }));

    switch (imgUploadTaskSnapshot.state) {
      case TaskState.paused:
        break;
      case TaskState.running:
        break;
      case TaskState.success:
        final fileURL =
            await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(fileName).getDownloadURL();
        return fileURL;
      case TaskState.canceled:
        break;
      case TaskState.error:
        break;
    }
  } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
    //Todo: handle errors
    print(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm sure it Will help. I'm just actually away for few days, so i Will wait to be back to check my app before closing the topic. Once again, many thanks

Comment: Hello pr0gramist, i modified the code as you suggested but i still have the same result.

Comment: Hard to guess what could be wrong. You could update the code or explicitly add types so you can spot the issue.